# Pass Email list as an argument from other dag in airflow

Tags: python, email, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have created a custom email alert python file, I am calling that function in another dag to send email.
Lets say - email alert file is **`custom_alert.py`**

```
from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

def custom_failure_email(context, **kwargs):
    """Send custom email alerts."""
    dag_run = context.get('task_instance').dag_id
    subject = f"[ActionReq]-dag failure-{dag_run}"
    # email contents
    body= """Hi Team,<br><br>
            <b style="font-size:15px;color:red;">Airflow job on error, please find details below.</b>
            Thank you!,<br>
            )
    email_list = ['aditya.dhanraj@gmail.com', 'something@gmail.com']
    for i in range(len(email_list)):
        send_email(str(email_list[i]),subject,body)
```

In Parent DAG : Lets Say `**email.py**` - I am calling the above function to send failure email.

```
from custom_alert import custom_failure_email
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['noreply@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'on_failure_callback': custom_failure_email}
```

This way I am able to send the custom email, but my recipient list is same for every dag.
Please let me know, How I can customize it to send different recipient email address for different dag. **How I can pass recipient email address from Parent Dag.**?

Comment: import stmt: from airflow.models import Variable

you can set the variable from parent dag like this:
Variable.update(key='email_list', value=['a.com,b.com,c.com'])

and 

use the email list in child dag like this:

my_list = Variable.get("email_list")
emails = my_list.split(",")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to set `params` dict in your `DAG` then retrieve this value from the context.

```py
def custom_failure_email(context):
    """Send custom email alerts."""
    #...
    email_list = context['dag'].params['mailing_list']
    for i in range(len(email_list)):
        send_email(str(email_list[i]),subject,body)

default_args = {
    #....
    'params': {
        'mailing_list': ['address1@test.com', 'address2@test.com']
    },
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'on_failure_callback': custom_failure_email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to achieve this using functools.

```
from functools import partial
new_custom_failure_email = partial(custom_failure_email,
                                   email_list=['adityadhanraj1312@gmail.com'])
                                                                    
# Now Pass this in default _args
'on_failure_callback': new_custom_failure_email
```

and we need to pass **email_list** as argument in `**custom_alert.py**`